# How to create multiple dataframe using same case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

How to create multiple dataframe using same case class? Suppose I want to create multiple dataframe one with 5 column and another have 3 column how I am going to achieve that using a single case class?

Comment: What is a dataframe in your context? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I have a text file which has 3 columns and another text file having 5 columns can I make two separate data frames using this file with the help of a single case class.?

Comment: What about loading your data inside a case class with 5 fields where all or the last 2 ones are optional ?

Comment: @RittikDe Please check the below answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create two Dataframe using single case class with the same number of columns directly. Assume you have the below case class `FlightData`. If you created a Dataframe from this case class it will contains 3 columns. However, you could create two Dataframe but in the next one you can select some column from this case class. If you have two different file and every file contains different structure you need to create two separated case class.

```
   val someData = Seq(
    Row("United States", "Romania", 15),
    Row("United States", "Croatia", 1),
    Row("United States", "Ireland", 344),
    Row("Egypt", "United States", 15)
  )


  val flightDataSchema = List(
    StructField("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME", StringType, true),
    StructField("ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME", StringType, true),
    StructField("count", IntegerType, true)
  )

  case class FlightData(DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: String, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: String, count: Int)
  import spark.implicits._

  val dataDS = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
    StructType(flightDataSchema)
  ).as[FlightData]

  val dataDS_2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
    StructType(flightDataSchema)
  ).as[FlightData].select('DEST_COUNTRY_NAME)
```

Comment: You are saying that If the two files have the same file structure in that case we can create dataframe using same case class. But if they are having different file structure in that case we need to use different case classes?

Comment: Yes, Same data structure it will work to create any number of Dataframe but if it different structure. You must create different case class.

Comment: @RittikDe Is this answer your question?

Comment: @RittikDe Did you check the above answer? Did it solve your question?

Comment: Yes I have checked and it is working. And yes it solved my question.

Comment: You can find it below the answer sign which means this is a correct answer